# SparkAppHandle.Listener.infoChanged behaviour

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am having a bit of difficulty in understanding the exact behaviour of **SparkAppHandle.Listener.infoChanged(SparkAppHandle handle)** method. The documentation says:

```
Callback for changes in any information that is not the handle's state.
```

What exactly is meant by **any information** here? Apart from state other pieces of information I can see are **ID** and **isFinal**. I can't see anything else. What's that thing which actually triggers infoChanged method? I can clearly see stateChanged getting called at each state transition during the course of the execution of my program. However, infoChanged gets called just once, when the state transitions from **SUBMITTED** to **RUNNING**.

Does infoChanged gets called only once, when state transitions from SUBMITTED to RUNNING? Or is it just in my case?

**Version used :**

- spark-1.6.1-bin-2.6.0
- java version "1.8.0_92"

Thank you so much for your valuable time. Appreciate it!